# Why is my test framework unable to find a URL defined in my routes file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm using Rails 5 and minutest and trying to write a test for a controller.  The test is

```
# issues_controller_test.rb
class IssuesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  test "logged in should get issues page" do
    sign_in users(:one)
    test_stop_id = 1
    test_line_id = 1
    get new_issue, :stop_id => test_stop_id, :line_id => test_line_id
    assert_equal test_stop_id, @issue.stop_id
    assert_equal test_line_id, @issue.line_id
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

The method in question attempts to access this page, defined in my rails routes ...

```
           new_issue GET      /issues/new(.:format)               issues#new
```

Yet when I run the test, I get this error

```
# Running:

.E

Error:
IssuesControllerTest#test_logged_in_should_get_issues_page:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_issue' for #<IssuesControllerTest:0x007f816759b330>
    test/controllers/issues_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:IssuesControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/issues_controller_test.rb:6



Finished in 0.103956s, 19.2389 runs/s, 9.6195 assertions/s.
```

Why is the test framework unable to find a method defined in my routes file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_issue` that way is just a local variable defined nowhere, try specifying it as a working url with `new_issue_url`:

```
test 'logged in should get issues page' do
  sign_in users :one
  test_stop_id = 1
  test_line_id = 1
  get new_issue_url, stop_id: test_stop_id, line_id: test_line_id
  assert_equal test_stop_id, @issue.stop_id
  assert_equal test_line_id, @issue.line_id
  assert_response :success
end
```